# Transfer Minecraft data between Xbox One and PS4

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

I have not been able to find any answers to this question:

My friend and I both have PS4's, and we both like Minecraft. We have a saved world, but he has it on his Xbox One, I don't have an Xbox One. Is it possible to transfer the Minecraft data from the Xbox one to his PS4?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The PS4s hardrive format has given those issues when converting file formats from Xbox 1.  Unless there is a way to do a simple file change in format, this is not a possibility.

Comment: MS and PC makers have never worked on cross-platform communication between Xboxes and PCs, yet saves can be transferred between PC Minecraft and Xbox Minecraft, because cooperation isn't necessary as you say, just file access and file format conversion. The question is whether such a conversion is possible.

Comment: You must also understand PC and XBOX have the same NTFS File system and the same file structure.  Made exclusively by the same company.

Comment: Xbox One uses an unreadable variant of NTFS actually, and the Xbox 360 uses FATX which is unreadable on PC, but different disk formats has never made transferring data between PC and either Xbox impossible. It doesn't need the companies' cooperation or matching disk formats, but the PS4 disk format *is* a technical challenge that may not yet have been solved.

Comment: I still stand by my answer, I will however edit my answer to better fit the technical issue.

Comment: Cool. Currently the answer does seem to be "no", for technical reasons.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to transfer data between the PS4 and Xbox One. The way I do it is to get a USB Flash drive 2.0 with a minimum of 16 GB and a PC to convert Minecraft worlds (So data can get equalized so that the PS4 can actually read it), and download the world from the USB.

Comment: Would be nice if you could expain how convert worlds. Are you using a software?

And what if I have a USB Flash drive 3.0?